# How can I start a conference call on GSM network?

Tags: arduino, gsm, at-command, phone-call, sim800

I need to make a conference voice call on GSM network.

The maximum I have seen in the datasheet is that the command `AT+CLCC` can report a list of current calls of ME automatically when the current call status changes.

How can I make conference calls with a **SIM800L**? I have 2 phone numbers for call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key command for the feature you are asking for is `AT+CHLD` *(Call Holding Services)*. It is important to say that this is well known *GSM Supplementary Service*, and since `AT+CHLD` is a standard command it is a feature that is likely to be supported by all cellular modems, not only SIM800.

The main constraints that any user must know are:

1. It is a service strictly related to VOICE calls
2. The network operator must support this service as well

---

### ETSI Specifications about multi-party calls

Though it may appear as a boring introduction, we need to build our procedure on solid basis. Feel free to skip this paragraph if you are just interested in the AT commands sequence.

**ETSI** specification [TS 127.007 v15.3.0](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/127000_127099/127007/15.03.00_60/ts_127007v150300p.pdf) describes its behaviour at chapter 7.13: *"Call related supplementary services +CHLD"*:

> This command allows the control of the following call related
>   services:
>
> - a call can be temporarily disconnected from the MT but the connection is retained by the network;
> - **multiparty conversation
>     (conference calls);**
> - the served subscriber who has two calls (one
>     held and the other either active or alerting) can connect the other
>     parties and release the served subscriber's own connection.

A further document related to **MPTY calls is then referenced** : 3GPP TS 22.084 (that can be found [here](https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=593). Another interesting source is [ETSI 300 954](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_i_ets/300900_300999/300954/01_60/ets_300954e01p.pdf) which states

> The served mobile subscriber A may initiate an active MultiParty call
>   from an active call C and **a held call** B.

This means that we can obtain a *conference call* just by adding held calls to active calls.

---

### AT Commands procedure

From the previous documents we can deduce that the following steps will setup a multi-party call:

1. Start a voice call with one of the parties by issuing `ATD<number>;`, or answer to an incoming call with `ATA`
2. Put on hold the first call by issuing `AT+CHLD=2` ([well supported](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/2/20/SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf) by your **SIM800**, that for `+CHLD=2` states *"Place all active calls on hold (if any) and accept the other (held  or  waiting)  call."*).
3. Start a call with the third party
4. Start the multiparty by issuing `AT+CHLD=3` (well supported by your **SIM800**, that for `+CHLD=3` states *"adds an held call to the conversation."*).

---

### About AT+CLCC

The command you mentioned in the question is not directly responsible for starting a multiparty conversation, but it is someway related to it. In fact, it is able to list the status of all the active calls.

Execution command `AT+CLCC` provides the following answer:

```
[+CLCC: <id1>,<dir>,<stat>,<mode>,<mpty>[,<number>,<type >,<alphaID>]
[<CR><LF>+CLCC: <id2>,<dir>,<stat>,<mode>,<mpty>[,<number>,<type>,<alphaID>]
[...]]]
OK
```

We will linger on just two relevant parameters:

1. **<id N>** is the ID of the *N<sup>th</sup>* call. It is relevant because many options of `+CHLD` command allow to selective hold/release an X call, and this ID it is required in order to specify X in the command. **All these options, not mentioned in the this answer, can be useful in order to select correctly the call to be added in the multiparty conversation**.
2. **<mpty>** is the *multiparty call flag*, and if it is set to 1 it means that the call is one of multiparty (conference) call parties.